# how to get list of rows count in sqlalchemy using conditions?

Tags: python, list, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have below table

```
class User(db.Model, Mixin):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    number = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

The values are as below for 5 rows.

```
(1,101)
(2,102)
(3,103)
(4,109)
(5,204)
```

```
user_number = data.User.query.filter_by(id=id).first().number
```

I am getting the result **204** from the above query.
I need the count of rows using the condition user_number. To explain this more on this, I need the result as 4 using condition 204.
How to get this result?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to get the id if you input the condition 204? To do this you would need to swap id with number. So if you want the id of the user with condition 204 then the statement would be

```
user_number = data.User.query.filter_by(number=204).first().id
```

This solves it because it is asking give me the users that have the number field as 204.
Let me know if this helps!

Comment: here, I need the row count of the table from the row of condition number=204. as per table, the row count is 4, how to get the count of rows less than the row having the condition of user number  204. 5th row is having row 204 condition, i need to get how many rows are below this row number. Hope my question is clear.

Comment: Correct me if I'm not understanding something, but wouldn't that just be `user_number - 1` @Anu28?

Comment: adding another example here, suppose user number is 103.How many rows of user present below the user having number 103? How do i get the count of rows in table?